# Header Styling CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I am currently working on the website: http://mdftanzania.com/

The website is made by headway. I face problems with the header, the logo appears now partly, the rest is missing. I resized the logo to a smaller size, but it still stays the same. I tried to do it by CSS, but I couldn't manage to do this. I use this code:

```
.block-type-header img {max-width: 100%; 
height: 100px;}
```

But this code doesn't resize the img, instead the text mdf tanzania disappears. I looks like there is a frame around the image, but I can't figure out how to get this larger after resize the height.

Comment: `max-width: 17%;` ????

Comment: the image itself is cut off: http://mdftanzania.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/mdf-logo-261x170.png, the transitions to your site are pretty sick btw, in your carousel

Comment: Make the height 100%.

Comment: The logo is covered because the height of the logo is higher than the height of the parent container.  In addition, the z-index of the header container is lower than the following content so increasing the height of the header won't solve your issue. Also, your logo's text is cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will size the image so that all of it is visible:

```
.block-type-header img {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
.block-type-header img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
```

}

You can visit [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/) to know about difference between width: auto and width: 100%